# Git: Deploying to Environments with Different Web Root Directory Names

Tags: git, deployment, development-environment, expressionengine, production-environment

I have an ExpressionEngine site set up with Git in multiple environments: Local, Development, and Production.

I have a couple of directories that are above web root, so the web root directory itself is inside the git repo, like this:

- .git
- system
- third_party
- templates
- public_html (web root)

  - assets

    - css
    - js
    - img
  - themes
  - index.php

Now, my development and production environments are with 2 separate hosting providers, and their web roots have different names from each other. Development, for example, is named `public_html`, but Production is named `content`.

How do I deploy to both of these environments when the web root directories have different names?

Comment: Git is version control. It has nothing to do with deployment. What do you use for deployment?

Comment: I use Beanstalk for deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using symbolic links on the server to point the web root to the appropriate directory is a time honored technique.  Let's assume you gave your Git Repo an obvious name: clientsite.com, so inside that folder you have:

- .git
- system
- third_party
- templates
- web_root

  - assets

    - css
    - js
    - img
  - themes
  - index.php
  - admin.php

That folder gets uploaded to your staging/production servers.  On the staging server, you would then create a symbolic link to web_root named public_html:

`ln -s clientsite.com/web_root public_html`

And then on the production server, you would make a symbolic link to web_root called content:

`ln -s clientsite.com/web_root content`

---

Now, what's brilliant about this is that if you are very clever and are using MSM, you can create config.php and index.php files that allow you to use web_root for ALL your domains in that EE installation and just create symbolic links to it for each site.  For example:

```
ln -s clientsite.com/web_root siteone_html

ln -s clientsite.com/web_root sitetwo_html
```

Then in index.php, you look at the HTTP_HOST server config to set the site_name:

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {

    case 'siteone.com' :
    case 'dev.siteone.com' :
        $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'siteone';
    break;
    case 'sitetwo.com' :
    case 'dev.sitetwo.com' :
        $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'site two';
    break;
}
```

Finally, your config.php can do something very similar:

```
$config['site_index']   = "";
$config['site_url']     = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['server_path']  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$config['cp_url']       = $config['site_url']."/".$config['system_folder'].'/index.php';

....stuff here...

switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {

    // production
    case 'siteone.com' :
        $config['cookie_domain'] = ".siteone.com";
        $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "111.222.111.22";
        $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "siteone";
        $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "passone";
        $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "database_live";
        $db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = FALSE; 
    break;

    // staging
    case 'dev.siteone.com' :
        $config['cookie_domain'] = "dev.siteone.com";
        $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "333.444.555.22";
        $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "siteone";
        $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "passone";
        $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "database_dev";
        $db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = FALSE; 
    break;
}
```

In this way, you can have global config options and then site specific options too.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using symlinks to create false webroots

I have the following setup:

**Production**

- public_site (actual git repo)

  - public (webroot)
  - system (ee system)
  - templates
- public_html (symlink pointing at the above public folder)

**Staging**

- staging_site

  - public (webroot)
  - system (ee system)
  - templates
- staging_html (symlink pointing at the above public folder)

Then you set your server up to point the appropriate host to the appropriate _html directory.

Comment: Could you give me a little more info to help get me started?